# Tridion + TMS: do these work together?

Tags: workflow, translation-manager

I have a large enterprise client that has both Tridion and TMS. Their preferred workflow baffles me--but maybe I'm not aware of Tridion/TMS limitations.

Here's the scoop: the client currently exports XML files and copies/pastes the XML data to be translated into Word documents. Those Word documents get manually imported to TMS for translation. When translation is completed, the translations get manually copied/pasted from Word back into the native XML format that gets re-uploaded into Tridion.

My question: can/will Tridion communicate directly with TMS so when Source content is ready for translation, all my client has to do is "push a button?" When translation is completed, TMS will route the translations back to Tridion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed an integration between Tridion and TMS, you have to check TM (Translation Manager), basically it will allow you to configure Source and Target publications as well as to select content for translation. Once the content is translated in TMS it will be sent back to tridion automatically (content will be localized and translated).

Comment: from the question it's not clear wheter under TMS he/she asks about SDL TMS or not....right?

Answer (score 3):

It's interesting that you are coming with this question right now, as we are finalizing a client side sofware/tool/solution for our clients, that could be used as a connector between SDL Tridion and different TMS's. We were facing with similar issues and questions over several years, for various clients we are working with. Questions:

**What kind of TMS is being used?**

1. In case you are using **SDL Translation Management
   System** to manage the translation process (http://www.sdl.com/products/sdl-translation-management-system/) , then there is an available solution for you: TranslationManager, it's a product that integrates SDL Translation Management
   System (SDL TMS) and the SDL Tridion Content Management system. TranslationManager is not part of SDL Tridion, you have to buy it as I know. You will have to make some configruation changes on SDL TMS and also on SDL Tridion Content Manager as well, to get it work.
2. In case **other than SDL TMS** is used or you would like an SDL Tridion-TMS integration **without any server side configuration** changes and installations.
   **We developped a tool that is capable of extracting content data on a user friendly way, from SDL Tridion** without issues and it's capable of integrating content inside SDL Tridion with most of other TMS's.

   - It's a **client side executable tool** that is installed on content editors PC,
   - has a user interface that gives you very similar functionalities as the TranslationManager does,
   - it can be used as a **connector to feed automatically content from SDL Tridion to other TMS's** or simple client side translation tools too.
   - Also it **enables us to import** back the translated content into SDL Tridion automatically.
   - it can validate the content components against their schema at the extraction process, so that you will be sure that the content you send for translation is valid and the translation process will not be a waste of time and money.
   - it makes backups of all content components, keywords, structure groups at the import process, so the import process can be rolled back automatically, all changed items affected by the import process can be restored right after the import.
   - can predefined in the tool for each content component type, or for schemas which fields and values you would like to include in the translation process.
   - doing this completelly on client side, without any server side changes required.
     If would like to get more details contact me directly: powerclient.tms@gmail.com, or skype: powerclient.tms . 
     To be honest this client side tool could even be used to produce translatable content to SDL TMS too.

Regards,
bvl

Comment: BTW, with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 we added support for the Language Cloud https://languagecloud.sdl.com/ and SDL WorldServer support was added in 2011 SP1.

Comment: Translation Manager is part of SDL Tridion since Tridion 2011 SP1, so it is just a box to tick in the installer, and an Xml file to configure on the Tridion side.

Comment: So TranlsationManager is for free? I'm a little confused with this information, you say it's included in all Tridion 2011 SP1 and 2013 version too. However as I know it's not a universal tool, which could be used to connect/integrate with other TMS's except the mentioned ones.

Comment: If you use Language Cloud, it is free (obviously you pay for the actual translations). If you use WorldServer or TMS there is a license fee involved, though I'm unsure on how much (check with your SDL Sales contact). TM was never intended to be a "one size fits all" generic connector, it is used to connect to SDL's own translation services.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link for the architectural flow of translation manager

Requires Login to view [Translation Process](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=TranslationProcess.xml&docid=concept_0BF32E7A412B44EAA8118BB59DC5A6E8&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_0BF32E7A412B44EAA8118BB59DC5A6E8) and [Translation Manager System Diagram](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=PR_productOverview_diagram.xml&docid=concept_63BD080C26BD4B229FE1351156989F4A&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_63BD080C26BD4B229FE1351156989F4A)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my blog post here, which explains the interaction between SDL Tridion and Translation Management System:

http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/translation-manager-and-sdl-tridion/